# Estou com um ploblema no meu código em JS

Tags: javascript, html

Eu criei um input no HTML, mas estou precisando colocar o valordesse input em uma variável. Sim, já tentei usar o `queryselector` o `getelementbyid` e não funcionou.

Quero fazer um sistema de velocidade e só preciso dessa variável se vocês virem mais alguma coisa de erro no meu código avisem please.

```js
  var b = document.getElementById("botao")

  var v1 = document.getElementsByid('num1')

  var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")

  function clicar() {
    if (v1 >= v2) {
      alert("você estar com uma velocidade alta ")
    } else {
      alert("voce estar com uma velocidade normal")
    }
  }
```

```css
    section {
      background-color: rgb(88, 230, 255);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-clip: initial;
      background-position: 30px;
      font-size: large;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 20px;
      scrollbar-shadow-color: rgb(151, 255, 233);
    }
    
    h2 {
      border-bottom-color: aliceblue;
      color: rgb(255, 136, 136);
      text-align: center;
      font: x-small;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    }
    
    input#button {
      font-style: oblique;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
  <h1><strong> Bem vindo ao sistema de velocidade do detran</strong></h1>

  <section>
    <div id="n1">
      <input type="number" name="n1" id="num1"> Qual é o limite máximo de velocidade dessa área?
    </div>
    <input type="number" name="n2" id="num2"> Qual é a sua velocidade?
  </section>
  <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="clicar()">

  <h2>obrigado por testar</h2>
```

Comment: Na linha `var v1 = document.getElementsByid('num1')` está escrito errado. O correto é `var v1 = document.getElementById('num1')`

Comment: Obrigado Vou rodar aq e vê se funciona

Comment: Ñ deu certo o ploblema no código e que qnd bota a velocidade ele nunca diz o if so diz o else,mesmo com o valor null ele ignora

Comment: O correto é `var v1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;` e `var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2").value;` faltou usar a propriedade `value`.

Comment: Ta certo,muito obrigado e costume de converas via chat instantâneo

Comment: Não foi uma bronca, Hoje eu sou um velho, mas comecei a programar quando criança e fui muito humilhado e perdi muitas oportunidades por não saber me comunicar com os adultos na época.

Comment: Mesmo assim obrigado,sobre o code acho que tem alguma coisa errada com ele  coloquei o .value;no final dos dois não sei oque ta acontecendo,deu o mesmo

Comment: Faça `var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[0].value;` O método `getElementsByName()` retorna um array. Agora funciona.

Comment: Só no v2? Ou no v1 tb?

Comment: Só o `v2`. Foi lá que usou o método `getElementsByName()`

Comment: Obrigado pela juda mais.... não funcionou! Melhor deixar pra lá vou usar o método antigo pelos prompts.

Comment: Aqui funcionou.

Comment: @JosePaulo quando colocar uma pergunta é importante ser claro no título e descrição, ser cauteloso na ortografia e gramática, bem como formatar o código adequadamente. Com isso fica muito mais fácil obter ajuda.

Comment: Só faltou comentário dizendo que as variaveis devem ficar dentro da function e que a condicional tá trocada

Comment: @JosePaulo conseguiu verificar as respostas apresentadas? Nas se esqueça de aceitar a que achar mais adequada e botar em todas que ache boas.

Answer (score 3):

Há alguns problemas no seu código. Alguns são mesmo problemas, que não permitem o código funcionar corretamente, outros apenas atrapalham a leitura e construção do código.

ex:

- `var b = document.getElementById("botao")` se `b` não é usado, porque ter essa linha?
- `v1` e `v2` são semelhantes. Por que usar `getElementsByid` e `getElementsByName` no outro?
- Há um div com id `n1` e um input onde o name tem o mesmo valor.
- Os nomes dos elementos e das variáveis não são "auto explicativos".
- O valor dos inputs é lido fora da função e as variáveis ficam com o valor de quando o JavaScript é interpretado pelo navegador.

```js
function clicar() {
  var velocidadeMax = document.getElementById('velocidadeMax').value;
  var velocidade = document.getElementById("velocidade").value;

  if (velocidadeMax < velocidade) {
    alert("Velocidade está acima do permitido.");
  } else {
    alert("Velocidade está dentro do permitido.");
  }
}
```

```css
    section {
      background-color: rgb(88, 230, 255);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-clip: initial;
      background-position: 30px;
      font-size: large;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 20px;
      scrollbar-shadow-color: rgb(151, 255, 233);
    }
    
    h2 {
      border-bottom-color: aliceblue;
      color: rgb(255, 136, 136);
      text-align: center;
      font: x-small;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    }
    
    input#button {
      font-style: oblique;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<h1><strong> Bem vindo ao sistema de velocidade do detran</strong></h1>
<section>
  Qual é o limite máximo de velocidade dessa área? <input type="number" id="velocidadeMax"><br />
  Qual é a sua velocidade? <input type="number" id="velocidade">
</section>
<input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="clicar()">

<h2>obrigado por testar</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Errado** `var v1 = document.getElementsByid('num1')`

O nome deste método deve estar correto `getElementById`

Por exemplo, `getElementByID` não funciona, por mais natural que possa parecer.

o método document.getElementById('num1') retorna o `elemento` que possui o atributo id = num1

```js
var v1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  console.log(v1);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="n1" id="num1">
```

Este método é um dos métodos mais comuns no HTML DOM e é usado quase todas as vezes que você deseja manipular ou obter informações de um elemento em seu documento.

Para se referir ao valor do campo utilize a propriedade `value`

```js
var v1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  console.log(v1);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="n1" id="num1" readonly value=50>
```

A sintaxe está correta `var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")` porém, o método getElementsByName() retorna uma coleção de todos os elementos no documento com o nome especificado (o valor do atributo name) como um objeto.

O objeto representa uma coleção de nós. Os nós podem ser acessados ​​por números de índice. O índice começa em 0.

Para se referir ao valor do campo utilize a propriedade `value`

```js
  var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[0].value;
  console.log(v2);
  var v3 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[1].value;
  console.log(v3);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="n2" readonly value=20>
<input type="number" name="n2" readonly value=33>
```

OBS: sem o índice o valor retornado é `undefined` mesmo que só tenha um elemento

```js
      var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2").value;
      console.log(v2);
```

```html
 <input type="number" name="n2" readonly value=20>
```

Essa variável `var b = document.getElementById("botao")` não interfere em nada na execução do script e está aí de bobeira.

**Aplicando o dito acima temos:**

```js
  function clicar() {
  
  //essas variaveis serão recuperadas ao chamar a função portanto devem estar dentro da função
  var v1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var v2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[0].value;

    if (v1 >= v2) {
       //se v1 for maior ou igual que v2 velocidade normal
      //alert("você estar com uma velocidade alta ");
      alert("você estar com uma velocidade normal ")
    } else {
      //alert("voce estar com uma velocidade normal")
      alert("voce estar com uma velocidade alta");
    }
  }
```

```css
section {
      background-color: rgb(88, 230, 255);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-clip: initial;
      background-position: 30px;
      font-size: large;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 20px;
      scrollbar-shadow-color: rgb(151, 255, 233);
    }
    
    h2 {
      border-bottom-color: aliceblue;
      color: rgb(255, 136, 136);
      text-align: center;
      font: x-small;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    }
    
    input#button {
      font-style: oblique;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<h1><strong> Bem vindo ao sistema de velocidade do detran</strong></h1>

  <section>
    <div id="n1">
      <input type="number" name="n1" id="num1"> Qual é o limite máximo de velocidade dessa área?
    </div>
    <input type="number" name="n2" id="num2"> Qual é a sua velocidade?
  </section>
  <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="clicar()">

  <h2>obrigado por testar</h2>
```